# How to pull data into the form when user wants to update his info? django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I building a feature where users can click "Update Profile" to edit their first name, last name, username ..etc. It works fine. However, I want the update form to be filled with the data they entered before instead of having blank fields.

This is my form:

```
class UpdateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean_email(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use. Please supply a different email address.')
        return email

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UpdateProfileForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

And this is views:

```
def updateprofile(request):
    args = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        update_profile_form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if update_profile_form.is_valid():
            update_profile_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        update_profile_form = UpdateProfileForm()

    args['update_profile_form'] = update_profile_form
    return render(request, 'updateprofile.html', args)
```

This is also important because if they enter updated info into blank fields they'd have to enter all of them but if they were filled, then they can edit what they want and submit. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the instance parameter in your second `UpdateProfileForm()` call. It should be:

```
else:
    update_profile_form = UpdateProfileFrom(instance=request.user)
```